# I am unable to log in to Stack Overflow with Firefox

Tags: support, login

When I open SO in Firefox, I am unable to log in to my account. It asks me to refresh the page when I try to log in, and then it redirects me to the home page of website. But when I open this website in Chrome, I can log in successfully.

Can anybody tell me what the issue is? I cleared all the history and removed sessions and cleared the browser cache, but this didn't resolve the issue.

> (as experts say this question  has already answered and  that solution
>   I already use  and after that I ask this question. I delete all the
>   cookies cache and session every single thing from browser but it did
>   not work and after that I ask this)

Comment: i can login stackoverflow when i use chrome. But not in firefox @MoathHowari

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in safe mode (without add-ons running)?

Comment: what OS do you have? Which version of Firefox? The newest? I have no problems with Firefox&SO, it works now, it worked a month ago, and it worked in 2013. If this is a bug report we need to understand what is specific about your problem. Because for most users, Firefox works. How do you login? With Facebook? With Google? With other OpenID? With email and password? If you login with google, can you login to any site with google on firefox?

Comment: i am login with open id and my firefox is updated i am login with outlook id and my os is windows 7 @Michael

Comment: do you have cookies enabled? can you login with your open id to some other site with firefox? (equivalent: does your open id work in firefox?)

Comment: no i daily login to hotmail from firefox there is no  problem in this @Michael

Comment: strange. i hope someone can help you...

Comment: strangely I have the same problem that the OP does. I am unable to see my user name in the so toolbar above.

Comment: Same problem here! This problem persists irrespective of the OS (happens in Ubuntu and Funtoo).

Comment: Same here. Can log into Meta Stack Overflow, but Stack Overflow says it logs in and then redirects back to default - not logged in. Version 29.0.1

Comment: Same problem with with firefox 32.0.3 and Mac OS X 10.9.5